# Script to fix texture nodes after importing a file

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting

When I import an fbx, it has image textures that should be linked from their Alpha socket to Principled BSDF's Alpha socket, but right now link goes from texture's Color to Principled's Alpha, like this:[image]

I tried to write\find a script that would loop through every material and do this:

1. Find Image Texture node and get the name of a texture used, since I don't know their names
2. Replace Color -> Alpha link with Alpha -> Alpha link

Every thread I've found about Image texture nodes creates a new node for this and then adds an image. Tried doing it like this, creates an eternal loop:

```
import bpy 
nodes = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes
links = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.node_tree.links
principled = nodes.get('Principled BSDF')

    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects: 
        for s in obj.material_slots: 
         if s.material and s.material.use_nodes:
          for n in s.material.node_tree.nodes: 
           if n.type == 'TEX_IMAGE': 
                image_node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
                tex = bpy.data.images.get(n.image.name)
                image_node.image = tex
                links.new(image_node.outputs[1], principled.inputs[18])
```

Comment: 1 character indent is a travesty :D... Same as comment here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133779/find-any-node-connected-to-a-materials-displacement-input-and-replace-it-with-a#comment230191_133918  loop over the materials collection.  1 material could be used twice  by a million scene objects . _ie_  Need only make changes on a per material basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Loop the materials collection**

[image]

Loop over the material collection. Need only do this once per material, rather than for each object that uses the material.

Search for links from tex node to bsdf and from color to alpha socket, if found unlink old, make a new link, and print the image name.

```
import bpy

for m in bpy.data.materials:
    if not m.use_nodes:
        continue
    print(material.name)
    node_tree = m.node_tree
    links = node_tree.links
    # list comprehension to find those links
    tex_ps_links = [l for l in links 
            if l.from_node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE' 
            and l.from_socket.name == "Color"
            and l.to_node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED'
            and l.to_socket.name == "Alpha"]

    for l in tex_ps_links:
        # print tex node image
        texnode = l.from_node
        if texnode.image:
            print(texnode.image.name)
        else:
            print("No Image")

        from_socket = l.from_node.outputs["Alpha"]
        to_socket = l.to_socket
        # make the new
        links.remove(l)
        links.new(from_socket, to_socket)
        # remove the old
```

[Blender scripting connect nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145882/blender-scripting-connect-nodes)

Also note this one, where it maps socket index to name.  When playing around with languages noticed the names can be in a different language, eg *Color* in Spanish will fail the `node.outputs["Color"]` name lookup.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160069/15543

eg instead of name test used above, if we know a socket number eg "Sheen Tint" is 11 could look for `l.to_socket == l.to_node.inputs[11]` instead of `l.to_socket.name == "Sheen Tint"`

Comment: I LOVE YOU!
This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help...nodes are IMO a little tricky to code at first.  but you'll get the hang of it. Well put together question. Upvoted.