# Change node settings and connections for mtl imports

Tags: scripting, node-editor

I used mineways to import minecraft terrain, but when I do that the textures don't have their alpha channels inputted by default, meaning that I need to go through a ton of materials just imputing the alpha channel to make it transparent. Is there any script that can connect the alpha channel to all of the corresponding bsdf's?
[image]
In the picture the grass looks dumb because there is no transparency, so it is just black

Comment: Same as here?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160392/script-to-fix-texture-nodes-after-importing-a-file

Answer (score 3):

Try this. I had it laying around.

```
# Tested with Blender 2.90
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.use_nodes: continue
    for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED': break
    else: continue
    if n.inputs["Alpha"].links: continue  # skip if already has linked Alpha
    soc = n.inputs["Base Color"]
    if not soc.links: continue
    if soc.links[0].from_socket.name != "Color": continue
    tex = soc.links[0].from_node
    if tex.type != 'TEX_IMAGE': continue
    if not tex.image: continue
    if tex.image.depth != 32: continue  # guess if image has alpha channel
    mat.node_tree.links.new(tex.outputs["Alpha"], n.inputs["Alpha"])
    mat.blend_method = 'HASHED'
```